# How to compile a c file with multiple words name

Tags: c, gcc

I'm very very new to programming and mostly self taught (using command prompt). I tried to compile a c file that has multiple words as its filename and it showed error for all the words.

Example:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\toCompile>gcc -o Even or odd.exe
>   Even or Odd determinator.c
>
> gcc: error: or: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: odd.exe: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: Even: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: or: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: Odd: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: determinator.c: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

Do I have to rename the c files to one word names or is there another way?

Comment: This would be a great time to use underscores (`even_or_odd_determinator.c`) in the filenames.  Or drop the spaces altogether:  `evenorodddeterminator.c`   Or shorten for brevity, keyboard and finger wear:  `evenodd.c`.

Answer (score 5):

Surround the file names in `'` or `"`.

```
gcc -o 'Even or odd.exe' 'Even or Odd determinator.c'
```

But in the future, I'd avoid spaces in file names. Some build systems (`make`) can't work with spaces.